# How to send response from node to react to render a paticular component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am currently working on a react app with node as backend -

I want to ask that on one of the react component is a form when button is clicked this form make post request to node server and after doing stuff  in  server. I want react app to remain on same component and clear all fields of the form how should I do it.? PS: I know how node works but i am new to react.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preventDefault` to disallow default browser behaviour of submission of the form.

```
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('')

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  // tell the browser not to refresh the page after the form is submitted 
  e.preventDefault();

  // then call the API here
  API(email)
   .then(() => setEmail('')) // after the API call is successful, clear the input fields
   .catch(err => setError(err))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the values in the form on submit.

```
const initialState = {
 name: '',
 email: ''
}

const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialState);

const onSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
 // Do your stuff with 'formValues'
 // Then
 setFormValues(initialState);
}
```